# Why does my tar not work?

Tags: linux, tar

I want to install a teamspeak on my root server, but after downloading the tar file, I cannot extract it.

I use the command

```
tar -xzvf teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.12.2.tar.bz2
```

I also know that you don't need the hyphen/dash before the `xzvf` but I use it.

Still I get a message that says the file doesn't exist although it is listed when I check with `ls`

I get this error:

```
tar (child): v: Funktion open fehlgeschlagen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefun                                                                                        den
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `z` option is for `.tar.gz` (`gz`ipped) files.
`bzip2`'d files (the `.bz2` suffix) use a different tar option: `j`.

Try

```
tar -xjvf teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.12.2.tar.bz2
```

or (auto-detection has been around a couple of years)

```
tar -xvf teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.12.2.tar.bz2
```

Further reading:

- [Compression support](http://invisible-island.net/autoconf/portability-tar.html#comp_compression)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly <3 Ill mark this as working result in 10 mins :)